# What is the order format of the cast shows at the end of the movie Slow West?

Tags: ending, credits

I think most movies end with the cast in either of order of appearance (more minutes, higher in list), alphabetical order or seniority.

This seems to be none of them. Is it just random? Or there's some logic to it?

[image]

Comment: Order of appearance means who showed up first on the screen, not who had the most screen-time. And that is the most common way.

Comment: I always thought order of appearance means, main character first, then 2nd most important actor, and so on. Is that wrong? So movies are never by the order of most important characters?

Comment: @Honey "movies are never by the order of most important characters" nobody said that.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I can almost say that I speak English as my mother tongue. I'm not claiming anyone did. Just trying to understand the wording. Seems that I completely misunderstood it all these years. Order of appearance can also be interpreted as order of (most significant) appearance, while it can also be interpreted as sequence of appearance.

Comment: @Honey No, everybody has always interpreted as "sequence of appearance", since that is what those words mean. It says "appearance", not "importance".

Comment: @BCdotWEB Using 'Everybody' to claim there's no room for error is not welcoming for a new contributor.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker but there is a similar expression, *ordre d'apparence* in French, and it unambiguously means the order in which characters appear. "To appear" means that something was not present, and then is. Think about its opposite "disappearance".

Comment: English is my second language, but to me "Order of appearance" can only mean, the order in which characters have appeared. The importance of characters for me would be something like "Frequency of appearance". And I don't think that big studios would waste money for a person so sit down and calculate for how many seconds each of 100+ characters might appear on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entire question is based on a misunderstanding of the definition of "order of appearance".

Credits are either by "order of appearance"

who
was
on
screen
first
even if that puts the big name down here

or "order of *negotiated** importance"

biggest star
other
important
names
everybody
else

*Who is most important might be fought over for a long time by the artist & their agent & is part of the contract negotiation. Sometimes, big names with small parts get special "also starring" status which pushes them further up the list than an unknown actor playing the same part would have got.

Comment: Can you link any major movies that have it as "order of negotiated". I've actually never seen that wording. Must be that my eyes were not used to it. And how common is that?

Comment: Most movies are listed that way. They don't explain it unless it's order of appearance. Big star, smaller star, also starring, small part, everybody else. Standard procedure.